# How to apply character styles to certain texts using python-docx?

Tags: python, python-docx

Apologies if similar questions already exist. I tried to find it but did not find any.

I have a Word file, and in the file, it already contains a user-defined style, let's call it "cmd" style.

I want to find certain text and then apply the "cmd" style to that text.

For example, I want to apply the "cmd" style to all the text between the string "`c:\`" until the newline character.

Comment: When you say "style", do you mean "font"?

Comment: No, we want to modify style, it set font, line spacing, and also paragraph shading. If change font, how can we do it ? Maybe can try modify fonts and color, just in case. Thanks